# How to show page when DomContetLoaded

Tags: wordpress, http, web, plugins

How to display the site when DOMContentLoaded is done on the wordpress site, please help me I've tried the lazy load plugin, wp rocket plugin  to load the faster website but is still slow.
Thank you in advance

Comment: try loader and remove that loader after page load

Comment: @dineshkashera thanks for answer, i want to display page even though not all photos are displayed how can i do? Thanks in advance